# nodejs http request socket hang up

Tags: node.js, windows, http, firewall

I've been trying to send http reqeust by http node module by following code

```
const https = require('https')

 http.request('http://newportal.timesgroup.cn/Pages/Home.aspx', () => {
   console.log('success')
 })
```

but got the message

> events.js:174
>
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>
> ^
>
> Error: socket hang up
>
> at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:332:15)
>
> at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:435:23)
>
> at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:203:15)
>
> at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
>
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
>
> Emitted 'error' event at:
>
> at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:435:9)
>
> at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:203:15)
>
> at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
>
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)

When I switch the code to

```
const request = require('request')
 request.get('http://newportal.timesgroup.cn/Pages/Home.aspx', () => {
   console.log('success')
 })
```

it worked and got a response with 200.

Then I try to capture network packages by Fiddler, I found no package was sent when using `http.request`.

This error only occurs in Windows system inside our working domain network.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try https instead of http since you defined it https

```
 https.request('http://newportal.timesgroup.cn/Pages/Home.aspx', () => {
 console.log('success')
})
```

Comment: Got the same time out result with https request. I now suspect there are some group strategies ban http or https request from node js.